# hardware signal processor API? (for extra Android processing power)

Tags: android, signal-processing, renderscript, android-hardware, android-renderscript

I understand that mobile SoCs have quite powerful ISP hardware (for camera), and DSP (for audio?).

Is there a way to programmatically access this, for your own computation (e.g. with input data not 
coming from the camera)?
This kind of thing is common with the GPU. e.g. *OpenGL ES 3.1* has some support for it; there's also *openCL*.
Is there anything equivalent for the ISP/DSP?  If so, is it worth it, or only useful for very specific cases?

PS: I seem to recall an Android API that was supposed to unify all hardware processing capabilities (CPU, GPU, DSP, ISP), but it didn't take off. **EDIT** I think that was [RenderScript](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/compute.html), for "heterogeneous computing" (though not include hardware signal processors).

Comment: did you find an answer to this?

Comment: @dxpelou No. AI read recently that a recent android phone has a powerful DSP, and iphones do too. But nothing about an API. Why not upvote if you're interested? Visibility can lead to answers.